# Error Android - received HTML instead of JSON

Tags: android, json, http, httpclient

I'm working on a **Android** application and I'm trying to get a **JSON** response from a server which is configured to return a json object (".../current_user.json") when receives a **GET** message, but the answer I get is in **HTML** format and not in **JSON** format as expected.

I don't understand why is this happening because I did the same requests on the browser and with the program **RESTClient** and got the right answer in **JSON** format.

Here is the code I'm using.

```
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

            HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 10000);
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
            HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url_getiduser);

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(get);                 
            String sresponse = "error";

            Log.d("url get", url_getiduser);
            Log.d("pedido get", get.getMethod());
            if(response != null)
            {
                InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
                sresponse = convertStreamToString(in);

                Log.d("resposta http", sresponse);
                if(!sresponse.equals("error"))
                {

                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(sresponse);
                    id_user = (String) object.get("id");

                    json = object;
                    Log.d("objecto json", object.toString());

                }
                else Log.d("Error on json parser", sresponse);
```

Comment: When you examined the text of the HTML, what error message (if any) did you find? When you contacted the developer of the Web service regarding this problem, what did the developer tell you? If this is your own Web service, when you examined the request on the server, what did you find?

Comment: The HTML received doesn't have any error message, it's just a normal HTML from the website. I haven't examined the request on the server yet.

Comment: I suspect that you are missing or have html content type header in the response. You can clarify it by checking the response header. Can you show us the service controller code?

Comment: I got the normal 200 OK response status. The response header is "text/html" type and it is expected to be "json".
Here is the log I got for the status and header:  http://postimage.org/image/uhyvm3b3z/

Answer (score 1):

There are few cases where you get **HTML text**

1. You might have called a wrong function which gives a 404 page.
2. Might be a database error on server side where you will get **database error** message
3. Server might be sending a styled data which has **HTML tags**

But you better Log the response and paste it here.

Comment: I got the normal 200 OK response status. Here is the log of the response content with the HTML I got:

http://postimage.org/image/9ojnivm8r/