# Android JSON request from PHP server - JSON Mismatch Exception

Tags: android, json, rest

Using this function I read in the JSON data into the objects and then attempt to print their ids:

```
private void getJsonData(String url) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == 200) { // success!
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line);
            }
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonObject.length(); i++) {
                Toast.makeText(context, jsonObject.getString("id"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(">>", "Failed to download file");
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I get this error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzLEC.jpg

Any ideas? It errors at the line:

```
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

My php:

```
    $this->db->select('id, unit_number');
    $this->db->from('parts');
    $this->db->order_by('unit_number', 'desc');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    echo json_encode($query->result());
```

Comment: means u are not getting valid json string form server plz post full response which u are getting from server

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK looks as if my JSON gets cutoff at the end for some reason mid object. Hmm..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but seems that JSON you send from your server is somehow different from standard JSON format used by android(?). Anyway would be better to see full string response you are getting from the server.

Make sure you are receiving JSON and not HTML. [Error Android - received HTML instead of JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13893058/error-android-received-html-instead-of-json)